# VBA Macro to Highlight / Delete Empty Cells in Table

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I have a table from A1:C250. A1 is a merged cell that has the name of the table and A2,B2 and C2 are headers for the following rows. A3:A250, B3:B250 and C3:C250 is all data.

Some of the cells in B and C do not have any words, and I want to program a macro that will go through and highlight and delete the entire row if there is an empty cell in the table. I also want to make sure that the macro is not bound to only 250 rows, because I will be using this month to month and some months may have more or less than 250 data points.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What have you tried? What you're trying to do is a commonly asked question, look for how to remove a row based on data, how to find last row, etc. and please share any code you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A3").Select
start = ActiveCell.Row
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
end = ActiveCell.Row
rng = Application.Range("A3:C"& end )
For Each cel In rng.Cells
       If isEmpty(cel) Then
           cel.Select 
           With Selection.Interior
               .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               .Color = 65535
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .PatternTintAndShade = 0
           End With
       Else
       'Do nothing
       End If
Next cel
```